# Parsing mixed text and xml nodes with Xstream

Tags: xml, parsing, xstream

I'm trying to parse xml done like this:

```
<foreign lang="gre">&lsquo;<LM lemma="auieo" catg="fg">auieo</LM>&rsquo;</foreign>
```

I'm using Xstream, and I tried to write a specific Converter, but it does not work :(
I don't understand how to split the content of foreign in 'text' blocks and in the 
Lemma xml (I've a specific Converter for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xstream is not able to parse mixed content. I preprocessed the xml with xslt and transfored it to unmixed xml, with this command:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
     <t> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </t>
</xsl:template>
```